Events loaded with delay in resourceTimeline only safari
Events in the resourceTimeline view are loaded with a delay. It looks like they are cut in the middle and after a few seconds, they are rendered fully.
GIF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qELId9ST4tQEJpMqWYkgWsaXYE8z_8EZ/view?usp=sharing
How can I debug this behavior? It does not occur on Chrome, which is why I cannot use performance features to debug it.
